# HTML Image not showing in chrome, and jQuery change not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have 2 problems as the title says, the first one is very odd, the other is probably me not knowing jQuery enough.

Here is the first:

I have an image that isn't showing in google chrome, it works locally, it works online on firefox and IE 7, but not on google chrome.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="advert">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/advert.png" alt="publicité">
    </a>
</div>
```

I also decided, to be sure, to add float:left, display block, height and width to all of these elements in the CSS. Google chrome inspector doesn't even shough the HTML  tag though.

Seconde problem is (sorry if 2 questions aren't  allowed, if so I will create another subject):

I have a jQuery code to change the content of a div using a option box, it works on Firefox, Chrome, IE8. But not on IE7.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <select id="bloc">
       <option value="france">Régions administratives</option>
       <option value="meunerie">Régions meunières</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="cartes-choix">
    <div class="france">
        //Image here
    </div>
    <div class="meunerie">
        //Image here
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#bloc').change(function(){
            $('.france').hide();
            $('.meunerie').hide();
            $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
     });
});
```

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Isn't this a bit simpler? `$('.cartes-choix > div').hide();`

Comment: With regards to your first problem can you provide a link to your site or recreate the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @roXon that actually worked, didn't even think of it, thanks alot !

Comment: `not on IE7` this will have issues with `html5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem.

Please check you haven't installed any add blocker extension in chrome? If you have installed then please disable it and then try.

Or just disable all extensions in chrome and try.

Comment: This worked, didn't know adblock blocked adverts HTML wise, I thought it would only look for jsscripts that google / other companys provide. I feel really stupid right now, thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing "/" in the img tag:

```
<div class="advert">
<a href="#">
    <img src="img/advert.png" alt="publicité" />
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to ass that I am using HTML5, so no real need to use '/>' since it is obsolete. Also my html is valid using W3C's validator

Comment: can you please link me to your website or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can  post your code in  http://jsfiddle.net/ 
may be the problem with image-bit or colour-scheme change those using photoshop